# JDialogs se repiten

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la cual llamo varios JInternalFrame desde un menu. Dichos JInternalFrames abren a su vez unos JDialog.
El problema se presenta cuando abro por segunda, tercera y así sucesivamente dichos frames, porque al llamar los dialogs, estos se abres tantas veces según haya abierto el frame anteriormente. Es decir, si la abro por primera vez, al llamar el dialog este se muestra normalmente. Si la abro por segunda vez, el JInternalFrame se ejecuta normalmente, pero el dialog se abre dos veces, luego tres veces y así sucesivamente.
El código que uso para llamar el JInternalFrame es el siguiente:

```
public void abrir_vtClientes(){
  vtCliente v = new vtCliente();
  boolean mostrar=true;
  for (int a=0;a<dsk.getComponentCount();a++){     // verificar si es instancia de algun componente que ya este en el jdesktoppane
    if( v.getClass().isInstance( dsk.getComponent(a) )){
       mostrar=false; 
    }
  }
  if(mostrar){
    vtCliente.rbAlumnos.setSelected(true);
    dsk.add(v);
     v.setSize(800,600);
  }
  v.show();  
}
```

Y el llamado al jdialog es este:

```
dlgCliente.setSize(900,400);
dlgCliente.setModal(true);
dlgCliente.setVisible(true);
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda prestada

Answer (score 1):

Investigando un poco resolví mi duda.
Les cuelgo aquí el código por si acaso les es útil.
Lo primero que hice fue llamar las ventanas desde una clase(Controlador) de mi escritorio, de la siguiente manera:

```
public class dskTop {

     private static vtCliente cli;



public static void abrir_vtClientes(JDesktopPane desk){
    if(cli != null && !cli.isShowing()){
        cli.show();
        desk.remove(cli);
        try{
            desk.add(cli, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER); 
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException ex){               
            desk.add(cli, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);                
        }  
    }
    if(cli == null)
    {
      cli = new vtCliente();
      cli.rbAlumnos.setSelected(true);
      desk.add(cli, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    } 
   activarVentana(desk,cli);
}
```

Y este es el método activarVentana() que se ubica en la misma clase

```
private static void activarVentana(JDesktopPane desk,JInternalFrame vnt)
{
    try {
        vnt.setSelected(true);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(dskTop.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    desk.setPosition(vnt, 0);
}
}//fin de la clase dskTop
```

Luego desde la ventana escritorio, el menuItem que llama a mi ventana lo programé con el siguiente código:

```
private void mniClienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    dskTop.abrir_vtClientes(dsk);//Donde dsk es el nombre de la variable JDesktopPane
}
```

De esta manera funcionó perfectamente la aplicación. Espero ser de ayuda a quienes tengan una situación como la mía.
Saludos.